# Moblenet V2: Importing graph with lower producer version into a graph with higher producer version

Tags: python, tensorflow, pre-trained-model, transfer-learning

I developing a transfer learning application where I am retraining MobileNetV2 for my data stream.

I am retraining the model with [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) from tensorflow-hub and have made no modifications.

When I run the script from a terminal, I get this warning directly after the model is downloaded to a temporary directory in my user profile.

```
Importing a graph with a lower producer version 26 into an existing graph with producer 
version 27. Shape inference will have run different parts of the graph with different 
producer versions.
```

During my debugging efforts, I created a `test.py` script to find out where the warning is coming from:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

def create_module_graph(module_spec):
  """Creates a graph and loads Hub Module into it.

  Args:
    module_spec: the hub.ModuleSpec for the image module being used.

  Returns:
    graph: the tf.Graph that was created.
    bottleneck_tensor: the bottleneck values output by the module.
    resized_input_tensor: the input images, resized as expected by the module.
    wants_quantization: a boolean, whether the module has been instrumented
      with fake quantization ops.
  """
  FAKE_QUANT_OPS = ('FakeQuantWithMinMaxVars',
                     'FakeQuantWithMinMaxVarsPerChannel')
  height, width = hub.get_expected_image_size(module_spec)
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    resized_input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, 3])
    m = hub.Module(module_spec)
    bottleneck_tensor = m(resized_input_tensor)
    wants_quantization = any(node.op in FAKE_QUANT_OPS
                             for node in graph.as_graph_def().node)
  return graph, bottleneck_tensor, resized_input_tensor, wants_quantization


def main():



   module_spec = hub.load_module_spec('https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_96/classification/2')

   graph, bottleneck_tensor, resized_input_tensor, wants_quantization = create_module_graph(module_spec)



if __name__ =='__main__':
   main()
```

And found it originated from the `create_module_graph` function in `retrain.py`.  When I run the script from the terminal using `python test.py`, I get producer warning from above.  However, when I run `main()` from an ipython console I do not get the producer version warnings.

I am unsure why I this is happening when all I am doing is creating a graph from the tensorflow-hub repo. I have looked over the [version compatibility docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/version_compat) and did not see anything particularly relevant to the error.  Looking through the source [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc#L1255), it seems to indicate that my graph is reduced to the lowest version before constructing it.

1. Is this something to worry about?
2. Does it change how you will load the graph to make predictions?

Comment: Did you find out anything about that warning?

Comment: Not yet. I still have no idea what a graph producer version means. [Evolving graph def verstions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/version_compat#evolving_graphdef_versions) seems to suggest it could be something to do with consumer/producer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my tensorflow-hub [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/180#issuecomment-435374790):

TensorFlow Hub modules contain `tf.GraphDefs` at the core, and these have a format version number to help with correctly importing graphs into newer versions of TensorFlow. It so happened that this format version was bumped from 26 to 27 between the upload of TF-Hub modules for the public launch on 31 March 2018 and the current TensorFlow release.

However, we are currently not aware of any visible effect on module users from the reported change in shape inference, so our current recommendation is to ignore these warnings. They will go away with the
next refresh of modules.